# Delegated access to exchange online without user constent?

Tags: oauth-2.0, office365, exchangewebservices

Would it be possible for a background service to use identity of specific shared mail box user in conjunction with the delegated access permissions without actually requiring an end user to authenticate ?

How would this be achieved in office365 exchange services with OAUTH 2.0 ?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

> Would it be possible for a background service to use identity of specific shared mail box user in conjunction with the delegated access permissions without actually requiring an end user to authenticate ?

If you use the client credentials flow https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow so you service is then getting an Access token using a SSL certificate of client secret. It can then impersonate (so it not delegate access) any Mailbox in your tenant and send as that user.

If your on Office365 then you may want to look at the Graph API instead that allows you to have a much tighter set of permissions (eg you could for instance just grant your app/service SendAs rights) when compared to EWS which only allows full Mailbox access.